# Photoshop help creating blended text for a gradient background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, gradient, effects

Using photoshop, how can I easily achieve the text effect shown below, where the "merge vr" text is part of the gradient but is slightly darker and stands out?

[image: text blended into gradient background]

So far I have the gradient background but my text is one solid pink color.

[image]

I image I can apply a slightly darker gradient to the text but it's a lot of fiddling around with getting the right color and the right gradient angle.

Is there a simple solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the text to a slightly darker and more saturated version of the darker end of the gradient, I set the opacity to around 12% and the blending mode to Luminosity to get a similar look. You can tweak the colour values and opacity until you get the look you like.

[image: text effect comparison]

Comment: Woah thats really good! Thanks! Also, what font did you use? Your's is more closer to the original.

Comment: My pleasure. I used Helvetica but it looks like they used something like Avenir.

Comment: @penguino007 if this has answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.